# Commutative diagram in the Category ( Ex in GTM 211 , Serge Lang )

Tags: category-theory

There is a example in the book Algebra written by Serge Lang , page 57.

> Choose a object B in category $\mathbb A$ , define $\mathbb A_B$ as
>   the category of morphisms $Mor(A,B) \in \mathbb A$
>
> Suppose $f \in Mor(C,B) , g\in Mor(D,B)$ , then the morphism of
>   $\mathbb A_B$ is simply a morphism $h \in Mor(C,D)$ such that $gh=f$ . i.e three
>   morphisms form a commutative diagram.

If $h$ doesn't exist , then $\mathbb A_B$ can't be a category since there no morphisms.

However , why does $h$ always exist ? I can't derive it from any axioms of category.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $x,y$ are two objects in a category $C$, it may very well happen that there is no morphism from $x$ to $y$ (for instance in Sets with $y=\emptyset$ and $x$ not empty). In your category, the set of morphism from $f$ to $g$ may as well be empty (and this is the case if there is no $h:C\rightarrow D$ such that $f=gh$.)

Answer (score 1):

As Roland comments, it may happen that the homset $Mor(A,B)$ is an *empty* set.

A more direct example for that is any *discrete* category, which is defined on any set/class of objects with just the property that $Mor(A,B)=\emptyset$ whenever $A\ne B\ $ (and $Mor(A,A)=\{1_A\}$).